# How can I overwrite Yaml variables in Silex

Tags: symfony, yaml, silex

So I have this yaml config file.

And at a certain point I have to overwrite a variable when loaded in $app['config']

But it just don't seem to be possible? Are Yaml variables protected?

```
$parser = new \Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser();
$app['config'] = $parser->parse(\file_get_contents("config.yml"));     

$app['config']['sitedata']['sitename'] = "new sitename";
var_dump( $app['config']['sitedata']['sitename']);
```

It shows the Yaml sitedata.sitename original.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you cannot change an item in the multi-dimensional array. Don't why but you cannt.

But! You can change it the following way

Get the array from $app['config'] and put it in a var

```
$config = $app['config']
```

Change the array to your needs

```
$config['sitedata']['sitename'] = "new sitename";
```

And then put it back in to config.

```
$app['config'] = $config;
```

Works!